# YouTube streaming API

Tags: java, youtube-api

The following snippet taken from

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/java

shows an error in my editor.

```
CdnSettings cdnSettings = new CdnSettings();
cdnSettings.setFormat("1080p");
cdnSettings.setIngestionType("rtmp");

LiveStream stream = new LiveStream();
stream.setKind("youtube#liveStream");
stream.setSnippet(streamSnippet);
stream.setCdn(cdnSettings);
```

> setCdn(com.google.api.services.youtube.model.LiveStreamCdn)
>   in LiveStream cannot be applied
>   to
>   (com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CdnSettings).

[image]

Comment: You tested two different things. Can we see the other code?

Comment: I used sample from this page, create broadcast code https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/java

Comment: Why didn't you mention the link in your question? Can you please edit your question so that you can see the different attempts with the respective error message? Once working (as in the link) and once with your customizations that lead to an error.

Comment: I got around a bit and edited the question. Is this so right? Can you please rework this until it's true?!

Comment: Yes, wait a little bit

Comment: I think you are a troll. :(

Comment: I can send an image with error to you, if you don't beleive me

Comment: OK, show me: https://imgur.com/upload

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VgVdDkF

Comment: OK, so you can't get the example from the link to work? Why don't you put that in the question? I thought the example was running and you wanted to change it. Your reason for wanting to change it is that you haven't made it work yet?

Comment: I use the example without any changes, android studio gives me an error like on image which i sent to you-_-

Comment: Okay, now we're getting closer. The question looks better to me now than it did at the beginning. Have you ever tried to just execute the code without paying attention to the error? Maybe the error is only displayed by your editor?

Comment: No, i havent any other IDE for that, because, I'm writing on C# and, that API i want to use it for creating a java lib for unity, because C# doesen't support that API, but thaks i'm going to run that code trough Eclipse tomorrow